# Get value from parameterized remote trigger plugin

Tags: jenkins

I tried to use parameterized remote trigger plugin to pass value to a remote job following https://github.com/jenkinsci/parameterized-remote-trigger-plugin/blob/master/README_JobConfiguration.md guide. In the upstream job I input `a=b` into the *Parameters* field, but in the downstream job in a *Execute Windows batch command* step, when I tried to get the value using `echo %a%` the output is empty. How can I get the value of `a` from downstream job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make parameterized downstream job having `a` as parameter. I think you missed this point.